# Print rational values in python using tabulate?

Tags: python, printing, rational-number

I'd like to print a table of values, some of which are rational (a/b) and some just integers.  Can tabulate do this?  If so, how?  If not, are there any other options?

Comment: The problem I encountered was that tabulate converted my rationals to floats.  I've gotten around that by converting each rational to a string. Not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html
you can rearrange your rationals with this package and then print them as you prefer, for example with tabular.